# regex working with long lines

Tags: regex, string, long-integer

I got a lot of these strings in one txt-file:

```
X00NAP-0111-OG02Flur-A  2     AIR-CAP2702I-E-K9     00:b8:b8:b8:7d:b8          0111-HGS  DE       10.100.100.100   8   
X006NAP-0500-EG00Grossrau-A  2     AIR-CAP2702I-E-K9     50:0f:80:94:82:c0          HGS 0500  DE       10.100.100.100   1   
Y008NAP-8399-OG04OE3020-A  2     AIR-CAP2702I-E-K9     00:b8:b8:b8:7d:b8  HGS Erfurter Hof  DE       10.100.100.100   1   
A1234NAP-4101-OG02Raum237-A  2     AIR-CAP2602I-E-K9     00:b8:b8:b8:7d:b8  AP 2 Anmeldung V  DE       10.100.100.100   0
```

I am only interested in the first string and the number on the end of the lines. The number can be max. 99
So in the end I would like to have a output like this:

```
X00NAP-0111-OG02Flur-A 8   
X006NAP-0500-EG00Grossrau-A 1   
Y008NAP-8399-OG04OE3020-A 1   
A1234NAP-4101-OG02Raum237-A 0
```

I tried a lot of things with regex, but nothing worked really.

Comment: with what are you trying to do this? Bash? Can you show us what you already have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a general regex solution:

**Find:**

```
^([^\s]*).*(\d+)$
```

**Replace:**

```
$1 $2
```

The idea here is to match the first string and final number as *capture* groups, which are indicated by the two terms in the pattern surrounded by parentheses.  These capture groups are made available in the replacement as `$1` and `$2` (sometimes `\1` and `\2`, depending on the regex tool/engine).  We can replace each line with these capture groups to leave you with the output you expect.

Note that this may "trash" the original file, but if you are using a tool like Notepad++, you can simply copy this result out, then undo the replacement, or just close the original file without saving.

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I can think of is:

```
Find: " .* "
Replace: " "
```

This replaces everything from the first space to the last space with a single space, achieving your goal.

Note: Quotes are only there to help show where spaces are in the regex.